# Codeigniter Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active inside a helper

Tags: php, codeigniter

basically i am working on an update system inside codeigniter. My intention is to recurse copy directories from the extracted update file. Therefore I have created a helper file and auto loaded it so that i can test.

Within the helper file i have a function as following to copy the directory if it's a directory else copy the file:

new_helper.php:

```
if(!function_exists('directory_copy'))
{
    function directory_copy($srcdir, $dstdir)
    {
        //preparing the paths
        $srcdir=rtrim($srcdir,'/');
        $dstdir=rtrim($dstdir,'/');

        //creating the destination directory
        if(!is_dir($dstdir))mkdir($dstdir, 0777, true);

        //Mapping the directory
        $dir_map=directory_map($srcdir);

        foreach($dir_map as $object_key=>$object_value)
        {
            if(is_numeric($object_key))
                copy($srcdir.'/'.$object_value,$dstdir.'/'.$object_value);//This is a File not a directory
            else
                directory_copy($srcdir.'/'.$object_key,$dstdir.'/'.$object_key);//this is a directory
        }
    }
}
```

After loading in the helper i attempt to access the function from within my controller, as following:

```
directory_copy($source.$file, $destination);
```

Furthermore PHP has been unkind and provided me with the following error: **Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active in 'file location'.php**

Quite new to Codeigniter therefore i'm not quite sure how i can use this function outside of my controller and have it work.

Does anyone know how i can get this to work?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I have included: `$this->load->helper('directory');` in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new helper, you should extend the Directory helper, as the "directory_map" function you're using is part of the directory helper.

Create a new file "MY_directory_helper.php" add your function, and save it in "/application/helpers", Then load the directory helper in your controller;

```
$this->load->helper('directory');
```

You should now be able to use this function

```
directory_copy($srcdir, $dstdir);
```

Comment: That's exactly what i have done... and i have the error for being unable to access self:: when no class scope is active

Comment: I think it's because the function tries to call itself.